# Trying to make the Subdomain work as a Cookieless Domain

Tags: javascript, php, performance, cookies

A subdomain is not setting to Cookieless Domain

I have a website to which am trying to serve all the `images/css/js` through a cookieless subdomain setup.

So for this abc.com website, I made a subdomain - `"static"` and set it to redirect properly to the page assets. But after checking on various tools, such as Gtmetrix or Pingdom, they still showing it's not `cookie-free domain`.

I am stuck on what to do next that where I am wrong. Or I will need something to make the subdomain cookieless?

Comment: Is the subdomain served through a CDN like CloudFlare? Those often set their own cookies that you can't control.

Comment: no it's manual CDN, made by making a subdomain of my existing domain.If am doing right way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a four month old question, but have been working on this and what I have learned might help you or another down the road.

Setting up `static.abc.com` can work if your main site is `www.abc.com` and NOT simply `abc.com`. The `www` makes all the difference.

If your main site has `www` then setting your cookie's `Domain` to `www.abc.com` will share your cookies with all subdomains of `www.abc.com`. This will NOT include `static.abc.com` - `static` will not be considered a subdomain of `www`. So calls to files using `static.abc.com` will be cookieless. You will (probably) want to set your cookie's `Path` for `www.abc.com` to "/" to allow sharing of cookies for all directories under `www.abc.com`.

However if your main site doesn't have the `www` in the domain (a non-www or naked domain), `static.abc.com` is now a subdomain of it and they will share cookies. If this is the case, the only solution is to purchase another domain.

I have a `www` domain and I was having the same problem as you - the cookies were being passed with every file on `static.mysite.com`. My issue was that I had the Domain parameter of `setcookie` without the `www` and so the cookies were sharing with all subdomains of mysite.com (which included `www` and `static`). Once I added the `www`, the cookies stopped being sent with `static` (verified with GTMetrix).

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks so much mseifert :D , finally It worked. I was paying bunnyCDN from last 4 months, now I have my own manual CDN with this great help from you :))